# Akka complains to a generic parameter

Tags: scala, akka

I have a class hierarchy like this:

```
abstract class Class1[T <: Class2 : ClassTag] extends Actor {

  protected val val1 = context.actorOf(Props[T])   // ops!
  //..........
}

abstract class Class2[T <: Actor] extends Actor {
//................
}
```

However, it complains `type arguments [T] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [T <: akka.actor.Actor]`

How do I fix that?

Comment: Akka actors are not typed. This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547947/why-are-messages-to-akka-actors-untyped) explains why. You may want to use [TypedActors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.1/scala/typed-actors.html) instead.

Comment: Does `Class2` really need to have a generic type that is also an `Actor`?  Is it going to use that type internally for something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are not passing type parameter with `Class2`. Give the type parameter and it works:

```
abstract class Class1[T <: Class2[_] : ClassTag] extends Actor {
    protected val val1 = context.actorOf(Props[T])
}
```

Comment: @MariusKavansky Oops. Sorry I did not see the `Class2` declaration in your code. I have edited it.