# Where should actor messages be declared?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm developing an application using Akka, and a thing that kind of bugs me the whole time regards message declaration with the `Actor`'s. Where should I declare the messages? In the receivers companion object or the senders companion object or on some third place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Akka team recommends Message should be defined in the same place the `props` method should be: [in the Receiver's Companion object](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#recommended-practices) because the Receiver implements the `receive` partial function and needs to know about all the messages it supports. Also, multiple senders can send a set of messages (implemented by the Receiver), so you cannot put it in one single sender.

Comment: Could you please expand on *"The Akka team recommends"*? A web page would be appropriate.

Comment: We do recommend this :-) Added a link to the docs to Soumya's answer => http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.8/scala/actors.html#recommended-practices

Comment: @Konrad'ktoso'Malawski I don't see where the part about messages is in the link provided :(

Comment: Putting it explicitly in that section may be a good idea, issue created: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/16614

Comment: Wow, thank you :). I didn't thought this will originate a new issue, but nevertheless I am glad it improved the docs at least a little.

As for the message positioning, it seemed suitable, but I've seen it being declared here and there and everywhere and in the examples it is usually just a `String`, so better safe than sorry.

Comment: Is this approach possible when we use Jackson or ProtocolBuffer? If yes, any pointer to a doc that explains it?

Answer (score 4):

If [the official Typesafe Activator template activator-akka-scala-seed](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-akka-scala-seed) is of any importance regarding Akka's good practices the messages should be part of companion object as shown in the following `PingActor` actor (copied directly from the template):

```
package com.example

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, Props}

class PingActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import PingActor._

  var counter = 0
  val pongActor = context.actorOf(PongActor.props, "pongActor")

  def receive = {
    case Initialize => 
      log.info("In PingActor - starting ping-pong")
      pongActor ! PingMessage("ping")   
    case PongActor.PongMessage(text) =>
      log.info("In PingActor - received message: {}", text)
      counter += 1
      if (counter == 3) context.system.shutdown()
      else sender() ! PingMessage("ping")
  } 
}

object PingActor {
  val props = Props[PingActor]
  case object Initialize
  case class PingMessage(text: String)
}
```

Note `PingActor` that holds all the accepted messages by the actor (as you may've noticed it's not followed strictly since `PongActor.PongMessage` is also accepted, but not defined in the companion object `PingActor`).

From another question [How to restrict actor messages to specific types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5547947/1305344) *the* [Viktor said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5551034/1305344):

> The common practice is to declare what messages an Actor can receive
>   in the companion object of the Actor, which makes it very much easier
>   to know what it can receive.

Comment: Actually this example shows that message types can be (re)used across different actors. Maybe it's a good practice to put the _command_ messages into the companion object of the receiving actor and the _event_ messages elsewhere? Here the `PingMessage` should **not** be in the `PingActor` companion object, because this actor doesn't receive this message. The right place is the companion object of the `PongActor`. The `PongMessage` should be in the receiving `PingActor` companion object. But it's event-ish and could be defined in a neutral object and emitted by other actors as well.

Comment: @Sebastian sounds a tad too complicated in for my taste. If someone asks you "where" you wouldn't be able to answer right away – let's use simple rules here "in the companion" is easy to remember, and makes sense as it's "the guy who understands them", think about it like this "it's that guys *protocol*".

Comment: @Konrad'ktoso'Malawski I like 3 things in your comment: 1. conventions, 2. protocols and 3. treating objects/actors like living things _talking_ with each other. But the initial question was: _Where should I declare the messages? In the receivers companion object or the senders companion object?_ Sorry, if I'am too strict, but in the above example it's not obvious in which companion object the `PingMessage` and the `PongMessage` should be declared. The receiving `PongActor` should by convention understand the `PingMessage` in his _protocol_, isn't he? ;-)