# Pass an actor as parameter

Tags: scala, akka

For example, I have

```
trait Logger { 
  def log(m: Message) = ??? 
}
```

If I want to pass a `Logger` as parameter I would simple call `def foo(l: Logger)`.

But if I have

```
trait Logger { 
  def log(m: Message) = ??? 
  def receive = {
    case m: Message = log(m)
  }
}
```

,I must pass an `ActorRef` to be able to call `!`/`?` etc on it. But that completely breaks type safety - `def log(ar: ActorRef)`, and nothing says that it should be an `Logger` underneath.

So, in the end I'd like to call

```
class Foo(logger: Logger) {
  def foo(m: Message) = logger ! message
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, yes. That's just how Akka works, because actors can change behavior. See [How to restrict actor messages to specific types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547947/how-to-restrict-actor-messages-to-specific-types).

Solution 1: define a wrapper class like

```
case class LoggerActor(ar: ActorRef) {
  def log(m: Message) = ar ! m
}
```

And then use `LoggerActor` where you want to make sure you have a `Logger`. Of course, if you want to do it everywhere, you'll probably want to automate creation of these classes somehow.

Solution 2: Use [Akka Typed](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/typed.html). Note it's experimental. I won't copy the documentation from there.

Solution 3: Use Scalaz actors instead, which were typed from the beginning. See https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/tests/src/test/scala/scalaz/concurrent/ActorTest.scala for usage examples. For your case it could be

```
val logger = new Logger { ... }
val loggerActor = new Actor[Message](logger.log)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can specify that your ActorRef should implement Logger too:

```
def log(ar: ActorRef with Logger)
```

Comment: I'm still not sure to understand your porblem... Can't you apply the same thing I state in my answer to this logger that comes as a parameter to your class Foo? `class Foo(logger: ActorRef with  Logger)`??

Comment: Then `logger: ActorRef with Logger` would get method `log`, but it won't use `Logger`'s `receive`. So `logger ! message` would do nothing.

Comment: This answer will not work.  User code never extends `ActorRef`.

Comment: was suggesting for him to do so. but the wrapper or Scalaz version looks better

Comment: There's no way to extend `ActorRef` in a way that makes sense.